# Stop autoselecting while using tools

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I'm trying to use, (say) the "Elipse Tool" to create a few circles using the same centre axis.

After upgrading to 21.0.02, It will NOT let me use the tool again without DESELECTING the current shape.

1. Create shape.
2. Shape tool is still selected. NOT DIRECT SELECT.
3. When I mouse over to create shape 2, the cursor changes (to some transform icon) and left-click now moves "shape 1" instead of allowing me to build another shape on this centre point.

Illustrator is treating me as if direct select is active tool, even though it is not.

The only work-around is to create a shape and deselect it first.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turn **off** the Bounding Box. (`View > Hide Bounding Box` or use <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to toggle it on/off)

Seems in newer versions, with the bounding box active, the app wrongfully *assumes* you want to move or transform the selected object if you click on one of it's anchors or paths (even *with* a drawing tool active). I presume you are option/alt-clicking the center point of the existing circle... so AI thinks you want to "transform" that circle rather than draw a new one.

If you disable the bounding box (which isn't *really* needed anyway), you'll be able to repeatedly draw over the selected objects, even if you start drawing on an existing anchor point.

Alternatively you can *start* drawing a new ellipse *off* the center anchor point, then hold the Spacebar down while dragging to move it into place after you begin drawing. Basically, just don't start drawing on top of an existing anchor or path.

Don't ask me *why* this behavior was implemented. I find it annoying.

Comment: Good, @Scott. I also use: Ctrl shif A to deselect everything.